# Register a field template for a string format type in react-jsonschema-form

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema

I'm trying to render a field template only if the json schema property has a string type with a uri format:

```
"external_link": {
   "title": "Report Link",
   "type": "string",
   "format": "uri"
}
```

I know I can create a field template, but its not clear to me if I have any recourse in creating a template or widget, and using it only for jsonschema properties that has a type of 'string', and a format of 'uri'.